# How can I get BIND to skip resolving a domain and always send a specified IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm running a BIND 9 server. There is a domain I want BIND to not look up and instead always return the A record as an IP I set in the config somewhere.

How can I do this? I can't seem to find any config options for such a thing.

Comment: If you don't own the domain, then that's not recommended. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a zone for the host you want to lookup, e.g. "test.example.org" and add A records into it, as if it was any other domain that BIND is authoritative for.

https://serverfault.com/a/251489/57144

http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/hosts2bind.php might help - example zone file for download and can read hosts files and change to BIND format.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a zone. It will need the standard `SOA` and `NS` records as any other zone.
2. Configure an A-type wildcard record.
   `* IN A 1.2.3.4`
3. Explicitly define any exceptions to the wildcard rule.
   `differentanswer IN A 3.4.5.6`
4. Be thwarted by upstream software that detects the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should think twice before messing with the answers from DNS for domains you don't own.

But if you are determined to do it and think that your reasons are good ones, you might want to look into Response Policy Zones (RPZ.)

RPZ allows you to tell a recursive server to override the answer it would normally get by recursing and instead return a specified answer, which can be an error condition such as NXDOMAIN or can be RDATA of your choosing, for queries to zones that you have configured to be overridden by the RPZ.

ISC has some information available in the [ISC Knowledge Base section on RPZ](https://kb.isc.org/category/110/0/10/Software-Products/BIND9/Features/DNSRPZ/).